# Search arraylist for LocalDateTime range

Tags: java, datetime, arraylist, date-comparison, localdate

Need some help with the code to return a range of dates from an arrayList after user input.

**ArrayList mainList**

```
static ArrayList<LEntry> mainList = new ArrayList();

public LEntry(LocalDateTime date, String id)
    2018-10-23T12:05:22 A2315
    2017-01-13T10:09:30 A2253
    2018-05-10T18:55:30 V1225
    2018-05-03T17:44:50 R9952
    2017-06-15T16:25:31 A2253
```

My unsuccessful code:

```
private static ArrayList<LogEntry> range() {
    String sDate, eDate;
    LocalDateTime startDate, endDate;

    System.out.println("Start date:\n");
    sDate = in.nextLine().replace(" ", "T");
    System.out.println("End date:\n");
    eDate = in.nextLine().replace(" ", "T");

    //System.out.println(eDate);
    startDate = LocalDateTime.parse(sDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
    endDate = LocalDateTime.parse(eDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);

    mainList.stream().filter(i -> i.date ?? ((startDate.isBefore(i.date))&&(endDate.isAfter(i.date))).forEach(j -> Ranges.add(0, j));

    return Ranges;
}
```

I'm trying to use isBefore and isAfter to get my range but since they return true/false I'm having some trouble integrating it on my code.

My goal is to get the LEntries between the given dates.
Thank you for any help.

**Solved**, thank you @user7

```
mainList.stream()
    .filter(i -> startDate.isBefore(i.date) && endDate.isAfter(i.date))
    .forEach(j -> Ranges.add(0, j));
```

Comment: Glad you’ve solved it with the help of another Stack Overflow user. You don’t need to publish the solution in the question. Other users won’t look for it there, they will rather look in the *1 Answer* section below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there

```
 mainList.stream()
        .filter(i -> startDate.isBefore(i.date) && endDate.isAfter(i.date))
        .forEach(i -> {
             //your code
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and kind words.  

Was trying to complicate things... again.